# ${}$Inertial and non-inertial reference frames

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

If we have three frames of reference A, B and C such that frames B and C are both moving with the same acceleration with respect to frame A. Now let us assume that we do not know whether frame A is inertial or non-inertial, then are we able to say anything about frames B and C in terms of being inertial or non-inertial?

Comment: Are you allowed to conduct experiments in the non-inertial frames?

Comment: Thanks, Your question solved my question. If we were to conduct experiments in frame B and it turned to be inertial then frame C is also inertial but frame A will not be inertial. Is that correct?

Comment: I was more thinking like if stuff moves on their own and you have to hold them down it's noninertial, like how balls move outwards in a rotating disk or how you get dragged down to earth by gravity, but then if you add them as fictitious forces your equations might work again.

Comment: What if we assume that frame A is non-inertial and we cannot conduct experiments in frames B and C, then can we say anything about B and C in terms of being inertial and non-inertial?

Comment: We really need oracles in our lives

Comment: I misread your question. I think you need to state if the acceleration is constant or not to know for sure. I mean, if the thing wobbles and stays put for a while, is it you that wobbles or the thing, hard to know.

Comment: I assume constant acceleration.

Comment: Okay, then I think someone can work out the condition for the other objects to be inertial. Probably the nullspace of some map.

Comment: Dale's answer in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/692244/how-to-affirm-whether-a-frame-of-reference-is-inertial-or-non-inertial/692289#692289) gives a simple definition of when a frame is inertial. This has nothing to do with other frames.